# How to set object to VolleyRequest(POST Request) in this type of API?

Tags: android, android-volley

[image: I tried to set Request in this way]

I have an API link to send post request for creating the order,
 I tried to set Request in this way.
I want to send POST request same as request to send in my image (Postman).
I want to create order from cart using cartID and index of the cart, how to send please help me out from this.
Thank You :

```
public void postCreateOrderByCustomer(ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems) {
    String token = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.token, null);
    String endPoint = "https://prettyyou.in/cake/pos/api/customers/create-order?token=" + token;
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    Map<String, String> payloadParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++) {
        payloadParams.put("cart[" + i
                + "][id]", cartItems.get(i).getId());

    }
    Log.d(TAG, "postCreateOrderByCustomer: " + jsonObject);


    System.out.println("endPointCartGet" + " " + endPoint.toString());

    jsonObject = new JSONObject(payloadParams);
    Log.d(TAG, "postCreateOrderByCustomer: " + jsonObject);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, endPoint, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponseCustomer: " + response);
                if (response.getBoolean("status")) {
                    Constant.orderId = response.getString("order_id");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(DeliveryDetailsActivity.this, PaymentDetailsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.toString());

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            return payloadParams;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            return super.getHeaders();
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DeliveryDetailsActivity.this);
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);




}
```

Comment: Do you want to parse it?

Comment: no, i want to send request and get response

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Stringrequest and object request or Jsonobject requst